# Spliiting a result into four parts and place it in four different files and then reading the data to get the corresponding records using pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, plsql

I just need your help in this one.
I have couple of tables(Persons and Accounts).
First,I want to extract all the PIDS and I want the result to be split into four parts and write them into four files respectively(namely txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4). Now I want to read PIDS present in the first file(lets say txt1) and get the details such as Dishno,name and address corresponding to these PIDS from the table accounts in database and write that into some file final.txt.
Similarly for other files as well.
Please find the table structure in the below file with some sample data(file size is just 13kb)
Can somebody help me with sample code. That would be of great help.

http://www.2shared.com/file/qTEiJ2mO/tables.html

Answer (score 0):

You write to files on the host with the Utl_File package, and there are many, many examples of how that works.

I would not write the four files then read them back -- it would be more straightforward to write four sets of PIDs to a global temporary table, assigning each one a file number from 1 to 4 using MOD(Rownumber,4)+1. Then read the account data by joining to the global temporary table, writing person data with file number 1 to person file 1, and the relevant account data to account file 1. If the file number is 2, then write to that appropriate file.

Comment: Thanks David for your response. Actually my requirement is to store the result into four files and then at a later stage,I need to use those PIDs from those files to get the relevant data.
Also,how can I split the result and store it into four files.
Below example gets the result in only one file.How to store the result into 4 files.
spool abc.txt
select * from PERSONS;
spool off

Comment: Rather than spooling the file, use Utl_File to write it to a file from PL/SQL.